# Who vs Whom in an relative clause?

Tags: relative-clauses, whom

I'm fairly aware that *who* is used for subjects and that *whom* is used for objects. However, what about when the object is actually being modified by a clause? I have the sentence

> We can determine this by solving for the location of a consumer, ______ is indifferent to each of these stores.

Would *who* or *whom* be more appropriate in the blank? Would it be *who* because *the customer* is indifferent, or would it be *whom*, since it is the location of a customer?

Comment: Answered long ago at [dative 'whom' with accusative 'who'](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/9144/dative-whom-with-accusative-who) (psmears' answer).

Comment: Except that English does not have a dative case!

Comment: What do you mean by "we can determine this by solving for the location of a consumer"? It makes no sense to me, since "solving" takes a direct object, but there isn't one present. Where did you find this sentence?

Comment: I don’t understand what you mean by “when the object is actually being modified by a clause”. There is no object, and there’s no clause modifying the relative pronoun. It’s the subject, and the only other constituent in the relative clause (apart from the verb) is a predicative complement.

Comment: @BillJ “Solve for [variable]” is [algebra-talk](https://www.mathbootcamps.com/what-does-it-mean-to-solve-for-x-or-solve-the-equation/), but perfectly commonplace. Whether the equation in this context makes sense, I have no idea, since we don’t know the rest of it from this snippet.

Comment: I think the comma is incorrect, because the relative clause is "restrictive": it's necessary and not incidental that the consumer is indifferent to each of these stores.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The technique below shows how to decide between who and whom by replacing the subject to her or she and seeing what fits best. As Mr. Sanan points out in a comment, the resulting sentences are both incorrect because they contain [comma-splices](/questions/tagged/comma-splices).

Replace **a consumer** by **Jack Bauer**. Now fill the blank with **he** and **him**:

> We can determine this by solving for the location of a consumer, he is indifferent to each of these stores.
>
> We can determine this by solving for the location of a consumer, him is indifferent to each of these stores.

The second sentence is incorrect, so it should be **who**. If the second sentence was correct and the first was not we would choose **whom**.

Comment: Nice way to show how to think about the problem.  However, don’t you think it would be worth explain the source of JJJ’s misunderstanding?  S/he seems not to be clear that the case of any pronoun is determined by its relationship to the verb in the clause in which it occurs?  Now I read this, mind you, I recognise what a good piece of teaching your answer is!  I’ll upvote it!

Comment: But 'This is John, who you met last year' is far more idiomatic than 'This is John, whom you met last year'. As has been stated **many** times on ELU, 'whom' is heading for the archaic except when used immediately after a preposition.

Comment: Both sentences are incorrect, since the first has a comma splice.

Answer (score 1):

"Who" is correct here, because it's the subject of "is".

Comment: So should 'This is Jane, who you met last year' be considered wrong? That would be a hyperprescriptive view; in fact, there are stronger arguments for considering the use of 'whom' here less acceptable nowadays. But all this has been discussed on ELU many times before. Please don't duplicate.

Comment: Rosie is right: subject pronouns take nominative case, whatever one's preferences are for pronouns in object function. And she isn't duplicating, but simply answering the question -- and with the right answer too.

Comment: I answered the question as posed. Anyone who thinks there should be no dup should vote to close the *question* as a dup.